# Is Luffy's ship ever hit with a cannonball?

Tags: one-piece

The question goes for the Going Merry as well as the Sunny.

They are very often shot at with cannons by the marine or by other pirates, but I don't recall a single episode where a cannonball hits the ship. It always barely misses or is blocked by the crew.

Comment: Does it have to be cannonballs specifically or does any ship based artillery count? In Ch 215 (not sure what episode that is) while the Straw Hats are escaping the blockade surrounding Alabasta we see the Going Merry get perforated by iron spears from Black Cage Hina's fleet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about canonballs but Going Merry has been hit with projectiles. For example in Alabasta while escaping they were hit by spears from Hina.

Comment: Close enough :) I'm guessing they have not been hit with an actual cannonball ever.

Answer (score 1):

Going Merry was repaired countless times by Usopp; I think that in the Thousand Sunny the repairs are not frequent because it is the Adam's tree but they received attacks

Answer (score 0):

Before having the *Thousand Sunny* ship, *Going Merry* was the one which got hit and took damages but got repaired by Usopp. *Thousand Sunny* is strong so it could actually resist damage.